# How to Send an XML Data Stream via a HTTP Post Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I need  to send an XML data stream via a http post request. I'm finishing my first app and trying to add an sms sending capability to it. I need to send an xml file like this:

```
<sms>
<user> <username>Leeroy</username> <password>Jenkins</password>
</user> <source>000</source>
<destinations>
<phone id="external id1">5xxxxxxxx</phone> <phone id="external id2">5xxxxxxxx</phone> <phone>5xxxxxxxx</phone>
<phone id="">5xxxxxxxx</phone>
</destinations>
<message>This is a message</message>
<timing>30/03/14 10:10</timing>
<response>0</response>
</sms>
```

to a http address:
https://www.blablasms.cm/api

I'd like to send it as part of a click event, like this for example:

```
$('input').click(function () {
...
...
...
// make an http post request...
```

How can it be done? Can I do it with an ajax request? What would be a valid ajax request for that kind of use? Can I send the xml data as part of the url?

Thanks!

Comment: AJAX is exactly what you need. All the information you need is here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax. You'll need to check the API documentation to see exactly what information you need to send and how it should be sent. The link you provided is broken.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks! The link is just for example. What I need to send is exactly the xml data I provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var pathToPost = 'https://requestb.in/17x6jwi1'; // example path

$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: pathToPost,
  data: {
    user: {
      username: document.getElementsByTagName('username')[0].textContent,
      password: document.getElementsByTagName('password')[0].textContent,
    },
    source: document.getElementsByTagName('source')[0].textContent,
    destinations: {
      phone1: document.getElementById('external_id1').textContent,
      phone2: document.getElementById('external_id2').textContent
    },
    message: document.getElementsByTagName('message')[0].textContent,
    timing: document.getElementsByTagName('timing')[0].textContent,
    response: document.getElementsByTagName('response')[0].textContent
  }
}).then(function(response) {
  // handle response
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<sms>
  <user>
    <username>Leeroy</username>
    <password>Jenkins</password>
  </user>
  <source>000</source>
  <destinations>
    <phone id="external_id1">5xxxxxxxx</phone>
    <phone id="external_id2">5xxxxxxxx</phone>
  </destinations>
  <message>This is a message</message>
  <timing>30/03/14 10:10</timing>
  <response>0</response>
</sms>
```

Here you are, tested and it works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks! Can I just save all the xml data in a variable and then just send this variable's content to this url?

Comment: Thanks So much! Forgive for the question, but I'm really new to xml. I understand the ajax request but how do I embed this xml into my html\js file?

Comment: This JavaScript code ($.ajax...) just makes a POST request to a server. It is the server to decide what will do with this data. For example if your server is Apache you can use PHP and write everything inside $_POST to a file using PHP's fopen method.

You need some google searches!

Comment: Thanks, I meant, where in the html document do I store the xml data so the "getElementsByTagName" can get the values from?

Comment: Anywhere. As long as the JavaScript above is executed inside the document containing the xml code, the "getElementsByTagName" will get the values.

Comment: I'll just try to add the relevant fields manually to see if it works for me.

Comment: I can't really understand what kind of problem there is so I just made a temporary gist to show you a simple html page including your XML code and the answer's JavaScript code. https://gist.github.com/masterakos/7eb0377ad50c0ea4658b5086cc0834c8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155697/discussion-between-rocky-racoon-and-masterakos).

Comment: I think I understood it but now I get this message on my console: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: This is because your server doesn't accept requests from "unknown" origin. This website will help you: https://enable-cors.org/server.html